# Registration Form : No error showing but No data on mysql DATABASE

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to develop a registration form.

When I fill all the filed and submit the form, no error showing 
the server is connected but no data on mysql database table. Bellow L attached the action file of form. What do I miss? and how can I solve it?

```
<?php
$mysqli_servername = "localhost";
$mysqli_username = "admin_try";
$mysqli_password = "rFT5hePS5u";
$mysqli_database = "indepe";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($mysqli_servername,$mysqli_username,$mysqli_password,$mysqli_database);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 echo "<a href='index.html'>Back to main page</a>";

if (isset($_GET["submitreg"]))
{

       $id= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['id']);
       $country = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['country']);
       $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
       $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);
       $re_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['re_password']);
       $compnay = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['compnay']);
       $contact = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['contact']);
       $tell = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['tell']);


     $sql = "INSERT INTO registration(id,country,email,password,re_password,compnay,contact,tell);  
         VALUES('id','$country','$email','$password','$re_password','$compnay','$contact'),'$tell'";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

    echo "record created successfully";

} else {

    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;

}


if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo " record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
}



//$conn->close();
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: what is your form method in html ?

Comment: After `<?php`  add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` and check. Also seems like method is `POST` in html form but code is using `$_GET`

Comment: if you 'POST' your data this `$_GET["submitreg"]` should read ; `$_POST["submitreg"]`

Comment: you just gave 'id' instead of '$id' in Values. bring that $tell inside brackets.

Answer (score 2):

There are few errors in your insert query

- Remove the semicolen after `tell` in your insert query
- You gave `id` in values instead of `$id`
- `$tell` is outside the bracket

  `$sql = "INSERT INTO registration(id,country,email,password,re_password,compnay,contact,tell)         VALUES('$id','$country','$email','$password','$re_password','$compnay','$contact','$tell'");`

Im not sure whether that is your problem or it occured your copying your code..because no error was shown

Answer (score 0):

I think you mistake in insert query **remove semicolon** before **VALUES** keyword and if **id column auto increment** then no need to add it in insert query otherwise you need add it properly and **,'$tell'** is outside the bracket please make it proper

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO registration(country,email,password,re_password,compnay,contact,tell) VALUES ('$country','$email','$password','$re_password','$compnay','$contact','$tell')";
```

Answer (score -1):

I thing you need to add privileges to particular user to insert records. as you have declared `$mysqli_username = "admin_try";`. now go to `localhost/phpmyadmin` and then add privileges to particular user!!

Comment: vote down?? but this is useful answer!! you must justify atleast!!

Answer (score -1):

You are using $_GET check and for submitting the form which is wrong. It's always recommened to do POST request for form submission.

```
if (isset($_GET["submitreg"]))
```

But, later in your code to get the the data you are using $_POST.

```
$id= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['id']);
```

Please check your form method in html make it POST and change

```
if (isset($_GET["submitreg"]))
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST["submitreg"]))
```